# Not able to Mock Static method that returns boolean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

```java
try(MockedStatic<ValidatorUtil> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ValidatorUtil.class)) {
    Assertions.assertNotNull(theMock);
    theMock.when(() -> ValidatorUtil.isValid(configurator)).thenReturn(true);
    Assertions.assertTrue(ValidatorUtil.isValid(configurator));
}
```

I have written the following to Mock a class called `ValidatorUtil` which is being used in a Test to validate a String so I have written that `ValidatorUtil` should always return true but it is returning false always and it ends up actually calling the `isValid` method of `ValidatorUtil` which returns the result as false. I have tried with all matchers like `Mockito.any()` and `Mockito.any(Configurator.class)` but no luck. Please help

Comment: Does the code above fail (if it is entire body of your test)? Does it fail if you use Mockito.any() matcher?  Do you have your test in the try block?

Comment: Have you tried with PowerMockito?  
Static mocks with primitive datatypes won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
try(MockedStatic<ValidatorUtil> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(ValidatorUtil.class)) {
    Assertions.assertNotNull(theMock);
    Mockito.when(theMock.isValid(configurator)).thenReturn(true);
    Assertions.assertTrue(ValidatorUtil.isValid(configurator));
}
```

Shouldn't it be like this

Comment: No actually MockedStatic expects a function argument in the when() and it can be passed using lambda which i have done and it then calls apply on that passed function, you are showing for standard Mock not for MockedStatic

Comment: theMock.when( ValidatorUtil::isValid).thenReturn(true);

Comment: We cannot do that since isValid method expects an arguments and like this you cannot call a method which needs arguments